# How to get Nested results of LINQ Groupby

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

My code is as below

```
GetDairyHeaderInfoByEmail(id)
    .Where(p => p.ATTRIBUTE15 == id)
    .Select(jk=> new {
        jk.HEADER_ID_PK,
        jk.VENDOR_ID,
        jk.VENDOR_SITE_ID,
        jk.VENDOR_NAME,
        jk.ADDRESS_LINE1,
        jk.ATTRIBUTE15
    })
    .GroupBy(p => p.HEADER_ID_PK)
    .Select(p => new {
        header_id_pk = p.Key,
        invoice_id_pk = _ippDetailServices.GetDairyHeaderInfoByEmail(id).Where(k => k.HEADER_ID_PK == p.Key).Select(c => new { c.APP_INVOICES_ID_PK, c.INVOICE_TYPES, c.IS_HOURLY }).ToList() }).ToList();
```

The results I see is as below

[   {
     "header_id_pk": 800.0,

> ```
> "invoice_id_pk": [
>   {
>     "APP_INVOICES_ID_PK": 1058.0,
>     "INVOICE_TYPES": "EPP",
>     "IS_HOURLY": "Y"
>   },
>   {
>     "APP_INVOICES_ID_PK": 1059.0,
>     "INVOICE_TYPES": "CPP",
>     "IS_HOURLY": "Y"
>   },
>   {
>     "APP_INVOICES_ID_PK": 1060.0,
>     "INVOICE_TYPES": "WHT ON DIVIDEND",
>     "IS_HOURLY": "N"
>   },
>   {
>     "APP_INVOICES_ID_PK": 1061.0,
>     "INVOICE_TYPES": "L.P",
>     "IS_HOURLY": "N"
>   }      
> ]   } ]
> ```

But I want the results as below

[   {

> ```
> "header_id_pk": 800.0,
> "HEADER_ID_PK" : 800.0,
> "VENDOR_ID" : 12.0,
> "VENDOR_SITE_ID" : 33.0,
> "VENDOR_NAME" : Faisal,
> "ADDRESS_LINE1" : XYZ address,
> "invoice_id_pk": [
>   {
>     "APP_INVOICES_ID_PK": 1058.0,
>     "INVOICE_TYPES": "EPP",
>     "IS_HOURLY": "Y"
>   },
>   {
>     "APP_INVOICES_ID_PK": 1059.0,
>     "INVOICE_TYPES": "CPP",
>     "IS_HOURLY": "Y"
>   },
>   {
>     "APP_INVOICES_ID_PK": 1060.0,
>     "INVOICE_TYPES": "WHT ON DIVIDEND",
>     "IS_HOURLY": "N"
>   },
>   {
>     "APP_INVOICES_ID_PK": 1061.0,
>     "INVOICE_TYPES": "L.P",
>     "IS_HOURLY": "N"
>   }      
> ]   } ]
> ```

Sorry about the mess if any, this is my first question.
Thanks

Comment: Please 1) format your code. 2) use the code syntax for code and not the quote syntax.

Comment: I edited a portion as an example. I’d have done the whole thing, but I’m on my phone.

Comment: How do I do that, I dont have much options available in the Rich text box of question.

Comment: Thank you cwharris, waiting for your example. Thanks again!

Comment: Try to edit your question and you should see how I’ve formatted the code. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks a lot, learning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dairy = _ippDetailServices.GetDairyHeaderInfoByEmail(id).Where(p => 
p.ATTRIBUTE15 == id).Select(jk=> new { jk.HEADER_ID_PK, 
jk.VENDOR_ID, 
jk.VENDOR_SITE_ID, 
jk.VENDOR_NAME, 
jk.ADDRESS_LINE1, 
jk.ATTRIBUTE15 
}).GroupBy(p => new { p.HEADER_ID_PK, 
p.VENDOR_ID, p.VENDOR_SITE_ID, 
p.VENDOR_NAME, p.ADDRESS_LINE1, 
p.ATTRIBUTE15 }).Select(p => new { 
header_id_pk = p.Key, invoice_id_pk = 
_ippDetailServices.GetDairyHeaderInfoByEmail(id).Where(k => k.HEADER_ID_PK == 
p.Key.HEADER_ID_PK).Select(c => new { c.APP_INVOICES_ID_PK, 
c.INVOICE_TYPES, 
c.IS_HOURLY }).ToList() }).ToList();
```

I figured it out, I just needed to add those master columns in my Group By clause.